# How to take a list field from database for a DTO? Spring boot - querydsl?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

edit:

i think i am solving this by creating views in db.

edit 2:

yeah, views worked.

the original post:

I am gonna write my tables and I will give the main DTO (WorkerDTO) and the other DTO's which are I want to use as fields of the main one.

I want to get the list of WorkerDTO which contains a list of  CarDTO. How can I do that? I want to do it in one shot. I don't want to go to database again and again.

I will lose my little mind.

```
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Car> cars = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person personId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "motor_id")
    private Motor motorId;

    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "color")
    private String color;
}
```

```
@Table(name = "motor")
public class Motor {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
}
```

```
public class WorkerDTO {
     private string name;
     private List<CarDTO> cars; 
     
}
```

```
public class CarDTO{
     private MotorDTO motor;
     private String model;
}
```

```
public class MotorDTO{
     private String type;
}
```

I used QueryDsl's Projections.list(...) method to left join the list of cars.

I tried @Query("select new WorkerDTO(...")

I think i will find the question like the second one.

Comment: With using projections I'd advise to use two queries. First fetch all the workers including their id, then extract the worker's ids and pass them to another query fetching all the cars by worker id. Of course there is some glue logic to join the projections/DTOs but you will have a constant of two queries.

Comment: when there are a so many person, the loop take too much time, almost impossible. that is why i want to get them from db together.

Answer (score 0):

Default FetchType for @OneToMany is FetchType.LAZY. If you want get workers with filled cars you can change FetchType to EAGER but this is not recommended.

You can achieve that creating your own method which can return List:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT person FROM Person person " +
        "JOIN FETCH person.cars cars")
```

or using EntityGraph on existing repository method e.g. findAll:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"cars"})
```